# matter.js rectangle won't collide

Tags: javascript, game-physics, p5.js, matter.js

I am using matter.js for physics and p5.js for rendering things. I was trying to simply create boxes when you click in the canvas and then when the boxes reaches the end of the canvas it collide with a ground but ground won't detect the collision with the box. i am assuming the problem is that ground is positioned correctly.

this the code

```js
// module aliases
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
  World = Matter.World,
  Bodies = Matter.Bodies;

var x = 0;
var engine;
let frame = document.getElementById("frames");
var ground;

var boxs = [];
function setup() {
  //put setup code here
  createCanvas(640, 480);

  engine = Engine.create();
  // run the engine
  Engine.run(engine);
  ground = Bodies.rectangle(0, height / 2, width, 10);
  World.add(engine.world, ground);
}

function mousePressed() {
  boxs.push(new Box(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20));
}

function draw() {
  x = x + 1;
  background(0);

  for (var i = 0; i < boxs.length; i++) {
    boxs[i].show();
  }
}

var Box = function (x, y, width, height) {
  this.box = Bodies.rectangle(x, y, width, height);
  this.h = height;
  this.w = width;
  World.add(engine.world, this.box);

  this.show = function () {
    push();
    fill(255);
    let pos = this.box.position;
    let angle = this.box.angle;
    translate(pos.x, pos.y);
    rotate(angle);
    rect(0, 0, this.w, this.h);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    pop();
  };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.12.0/matter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.0/p5.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Ball Clash</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="frames"></p>
  <!-- <canvas id="myCanvas" height="480" width="640" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get into the habit of [debugging your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging). (That tutorial is for Processing, but many of the same ideas apply to P5.js.)

> i am assuming the problem is that ground is positioned correctly.

So why don't you just check the position of the ground? I don't see anywhere that you're drawing the ground, why don't you start by doing that?

Or you could add this line into the `draw()` function:

```
console.log(ground.position);
```

Either way, you'll notice that the ground is falling, which makes sense because it's a rectangle, just like the other boxes which are falling.

To fix your problem, you need to figure out how to create a stationary box that doesn't move. I'm sure Googling "matter.js stationary rectangle" will return a ton of results, or you can consult their documentation.

Comment: thanks man. it was obvious but for some reason i did not think about it

Comment: @salemsaggaf No problem. When in doubt, `console.log()` is your best friend! :p

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on [Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49433319/6243352), add [`{isStatic: true}`](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#property_isStatic) to the ground to prevent it from falling:

```js
ground = Bodies.rectangle(0, height / 2, width, 10, {isStatic: true});
//                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```